# How to Redefine Class Objects in C++

Tags: c++, variables

I'm declaring an object inside an `if` statement, and I need to access it in another `if` statement. The object takes in 6 integers and 1 float as its parameters.

```
        if(mode == 1){
            Enemy ene(10 + enLi, 10 + enLi, 0, 0, enL, 1, 0.8);
            Enemy dashF(40, 40, 10, 10, 11, 1, 1.6); //I need to use these 2 objects...
        }else if(mode == 2){
            Enemy ene(18 + enLi, 18 + enLi, 0, 0, enL, 1, 1);
            Enemy dashF(52, 52, 10, 10, 12, 3, 2);
        }else if(mode == 3){
            Enemy ene(24 + enLi, 24 + enLi, 0, 0, enL, 1, 1.2);
            Enemy dashF(65, 65, 10, 10, 13, 3, 2.3);
        }else if(mode == 4){
            Enemy ene(28 + enLi, 28 + enLi, 0, 0, enL, 1, 1.4);
            Enemy dashF(80, 80, 10, 10, 14, 4, 2.8);
        }
        if(en == 1){
            battle(ene, "Wolf", false); // down here.
            start = false;
            koltForest();
            return;
        }else if(en == 2){
            battle(ene, "Bear", false);
            start = false;
            koltForest();
            return;
        }else if(en == 4){
            battle(dashF, "Dashing Falcon", true);
            return;
        }else{
            battle(ene, "Forest Rat", false);
            start = false;
            koltForest();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Try declaring it outside of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside those first few conditions, store the numbers in variables, rather than the `Enemy` objects you're going to construct from the numbers.

Then construct the `Enemy` objects from those variables, outside of the conditions.

```
int x;
switch (a) {
   case 0: x = 42;  break;
   case 1: x = 98;  break;
   case 2: x = 115; break;
   // ...
   default: throw std::runtime_error("Unexpected value for `a`");
}

Type obj(x);
// Now use `obj`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the object before the `if` assuming it has a default constructor and then overwrite the value in each of the branches if you define a valid assignment operator.

```
Enemy ene;
if (mode == 1) {
    ene = Enemy( /* ... */ );
}
```

This assumes that construction and copy assignment are cheap.

If that's not the case or you don't want to define a default constructor, then you'll need to use a pointer or smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` to hold the object.

```
std::unique_ptr<Enemy> ene;
if (mode == 1) {
    ene.reset(new Enemy( /* ... */ ));
}
```

A better approach would be to not use an `if` at all, but to write your object in a way to use polymorphism.

Code like:

```
if (mode == 1) {
    // ...
} else if (mode == 2) {
    // ...
}
```

Just screams for a refactoring. At minimum `mode` should be some kind of `enum` and use symbolic names. If you make `mode` a custom class, it could have a `getEnemy` method which returns an object with the correct constructor parameters.